# Comparing an input value to an array value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm using an ajax call to get a JSON file using jQuery. While I am successful in doing so and can reach the values of the file, the next challenge is to get a value of the object array and compare it to an input source. If true then print it out in a span or div...

Here is the script using jQuery:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /*
    $.getJSON('zipcodes.json', function(data){
        console.log('It worked!');
    //test
}); 
    */

    $.ajax({
    url: 'zipcodes.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data.zipcodes).each(function(index, value) {

            console.log(value.zip);

        });
    }

});
</script>
```

the JSON file is:

```
{
    "zipcodes": [
    {
        "zip": "20002",
        "city": "Washington",
        "state": "DC"
      },
      {
        "zip": "10001",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY"
      }
  ]
}
```

The JSON file is valid but I guess I'm trying to figure out a comparison in values of zip e.g.

if a var text = '10001' == value.zip within the array return the city and state within the HTML I can implement that part but in the jQuery portion I do not know how to get an index. I tried using .eq and .get and it won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: You could also get the file content and directly convert it to an JS object using `JSON.parse(JSONString);`, which you could then iterate over using a loop.

Comment: Didn't understand what the problem, i just used your code doing value.zip == '10001' and it return true for 1 zip code, where exactly you are having problem?

Comment: Use `indexOf`, example: `var zips = ["11111", "12345", "12345"]` and check `if (zips.indexOf(value.zip) > -1)`

Comment: let me put it this way. I have an input text box in a form that would take the zip code value.. e.g. 10001 then compare that within the array and return it. I used JS object but I want to try jQuery as I'm new to it. The comment by tymeJV is not applicable because you are defining an array.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bmDe87kmvRdZVdylqwwN)
I am pretty sure this is what you were after.

Your jQuery each is fine. You just need to check the value of the inputted zip against the Array using jQuery $.inArray function to get the index:

```
$.inArray(value, myZips.zipcodes);
```